# I have TimeZoneId in Russian. How to get equivalent in English?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, timezone, nodatime

My app works with a public calendar via CalDAV protocol (let's call it CalDAV calendar) which returns events in iCalendar format. One user started to create events in that calendar using Outlook localized to Russian language. It happened that Outlook put TZID field in the CalDAV calendar event in Russian language, as follows:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID: some prod id
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:(UTC+03:00) Москва\, Санкт-Петербург
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19710101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=UserName:MAILTO:username@mail.com
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20230108T100000Z
DTSTAMP:20230109T101100Z
UID:russiantz001
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Тест с 6 по 8 в 13 00 - 13 30
DTSTART;TZID="(UTC+03:00) Москва, Санкт-Петербург":20230106T130000
DTEND;TZID="(UTC+03:00) Москва, Санкт-Петербург":20230106T133000
DESCRIPTION:Russian TZ
```

CalDAV calendar treats events correctly. To deserialize iCalendar event I am using [iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) library which in turn uses [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) method `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(TimeZoneId)` to convert time from a time zone to UTC. It searches all time zone providers (IANA, BCL, serialization, etc) to see if TimeZoneId matches. Unfortunately, NodaTime does not understand TimeZoneId in Russian.

**My question**: how to get a correct English equivalent of the TimeZoneId in Russian generated by the localized Outlook?

.NET method [FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById?view=netstandard-2.1) throws exception that TimeZoneId is not found.

My app works in Linux environment. Therefore I cannot use Windows registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` records. Moreover, to use registry records Windows should have been localized to the Russian language which would not happen for sure.

For now I am thinking just to use `(UTC+03:00)` prefix of the time zone Id in Russian, but I am not sure if this is right decision. For example, will time zone offset be correct during daylight saving period?

I would greatly appreciate any link or hint how to solve this conversion issue.

Comment: "Unfortunately, NodaTime does not understand TimeZoneId in Russian." Because it's not actually a time zone ID.

Answer (score 1):

Time zone IDs should never be localized.  What you have in the `TZID` field appears to be a time zone *display name*, not an ID.  The application that created that file is incorrectly using the `DisplayName` property of the `TimeZoneInfo` object where it should be using `Id` property instead.

The correct Windows ID that should be showing in the file is `"Russian Standard Time"`.  Or it could (preferably) show the equivalent IANA time zone ID, which is `"Europe/Moscow"`.  They should be those exact strings and not translated to Russian.

The iCal format itself (and anything consuming it) doesn't care about this because it is strictly looking at the `TZID` field as it exists within the file.  But anything else you use it for absolutely will.

The original application needs to be updated to return a time zone identifier instead of a display name in the `TZID` field.

Just using the time zone offset *might* be sufficient - but it may not always be.  For example, if the time zone is one that changes offsets due to daylight saving time, the offset in the display name won't necessarily be the correct offset in effect for the event in the calendar.

The offset might also be different on the start time than on the end time, if the event crosses a DST transition.  Moreover, if the event is recurring, the offset can be different between occurrences of events.

Then again, that particular time zone doesn't use DST (at least it doesn't presently), so you may never encounter such cases.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, especially for clarification about _display name_ . Unfortunately, your proposal to update user's Outlook is quite difficult to implement in that particular situation. I am looking for the solution that would not depend on users' apps.

Comment: AFAIK, Outlook would never be generating the file with the TZID as a localized display name.  Something else must creating that file.  That's what needs to be fixed.

Comment: If you can't change the source of the file, then the only thing reasonably to do would be to parse all of the data contained within this file to get what you're after.  For example, if you only need the local time of the event, the timestamps are already in that local time.  Or if you only need the UTC time of the start of the event, then you can apply the `TZOFFSETFROM` value.  You could also consider an iCal parser, such as [iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) or another.

Comment: The only thing you shouldn't try is to map from a localized display name back to a time zone ID.  The variation on display names per language is too complex, and they aren't stable. (Microsoft changes the display names occasionally, whereas the IDs are fixed.)

Comment: tanks again for the comments. Basically, I am coming to the same conclusions. I do use iCal.NET parser.

Comment: Actually, I need to use `TZOFFSETTO` value as it is explained in [RFC554](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5) p. 66
_The mandatory "TZOFFSETTO" property gives the UTC offset for the time zone sub-component (Standard Time or Daylight Saving Time) when this observance is in use._